# Change background color of TextView

Tags: android, background

I would like to know how to change a background of a text view, as I am pulling the data from the site parse.com, but I am not able to do, what I'm trying to do is this.

CODE

```
public class Pizzarias extends ActionBarActivity {

// Declare Variables
Boolean bColorStatus = true;
TextView status;
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapterPizzarias adapter;
private List<WorldPopulation> worldpopulationlist = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzarias);


    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
   // status.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pizzarias, menu);

    //Os metodos abaixo são para mostrar o icone do aplicativo na action bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    return true;
}


/*@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}*/


//RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Pizzarias.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Carregando Pizzarias");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Aguarde...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "GerenciarPizzariasPatos");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending,


//here is the implementation to search for the word "closed" and change the background color.
            query.whereStartsWith ( "status" , "fechado" );
            ob = query.find();
            if(query.equals("fechado")){
                status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                bColorStatus = false;
            }
            else {
                status.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                bColorStatus = true;
            }

            query.orderByAscending("nome");
            query.equals("status");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setNome((String) country.get("nome"));
                map.setEndereco((String) country.get("endereco"));
                map.setTelefone((String) country.get("telefone"));
                map.setStatus((String) country.get("status"));
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewpizzarias);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapterPizzarias(Pizzarias.this,
                worldpopulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

ERRO

> 04-30 11:56:59.156  28388-28691/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>       Process: com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas, PID: 28388
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Pizzarias$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Pizzarias.java:111)
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Pizzarias$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(Pizzarias.java:78)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>   04-30 11:56:59.590  28388-28388/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Pizzarias has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{3dc64751 V.E..... R......D 0,0-513,248} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:375)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Pizzarias$RemoteDataTask.onPreExecute(Pizzarias.java:90)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
>               at com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas.Pizzarias.onCreate(Pizzarias.java:47)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>   04-30 12:01:59.260  28388-28691/com.example.ronysueliton.patospizzas I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 28388 SIG: 9

Could anyone help?

Comment: This should work `yourTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`, but please give more information. Have you seen any exception or error?

Comment: @Batuhan Coşkun. I tried to show the best possible way.

Comment: You can't access the UI elements inside the `doInBackground(...)` method since the method is not running on the same thread as the UI. Is there a specific reason why you are using an `AsyncTask`? Since you are using Parse you can use the `findInBackground()` method. https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground%28%29

Comment: Batuhan Coşkun. Hello friend, thanks for the reply, I'm using a tutorial example: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/. It could change the code and suit my problem, my code is working only like to change the background of the TextView, when the word is found closed the color changes to red and when the open word was found the color changes to green. I'll see the tips you left the comment.

Comment: @marialena. Please's a look at my question and see if you can help me.

Comment: @bhatt4982. Please's a look at my question and see if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to work on UI elements on a background thread. Your variable `status` will be null in `doInBackground()`. Setting those colors will need to be done in `onPostExecute()` or call `runOnUiThread(Runnable action)`.

Comment: I did what you said and disappeared a part of the error now appears this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Sounds like `status` is null. Might want to check if `status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);` is actually returning anything.

Comment: Then I would have to change the value of textview?

Comment: If `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);` is returning null then make sure you have a TextView with the id of `status` in your `activity_pizzarias` xml file.

Comment: The status is so stated in the layout: `android: id = "@ + id / status"`, the part that you speak `(TextView) findViewById (R.id.status)` is returning null, that's what I did not understand, this null terial to be declared or added any value?

Comment: If `(TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);` is returning null then you need to add a TextView to your `activity_pizzarias` layout xml file and give it an id of `status`. Sounds like you're trying to find a TextView that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: now I understand. So what happens is that this is a list and that item "status" is located in another .xml file (item_lista_pizzarias), then I would have to call something with item_lista_pizzarias into the class?